# Como crear correctamente el permiso de usuario en codeigniter 4

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de permisos para usuarios que tengan por defecto dos roles, administrador o usuario, en este caso el usuario se llama empresa.

La idea es que al registrarse siempre se le dará permiso de empresa, a no ser que un administrador cambie el permiso posteriormente.

Tengo las siguientes tablas.

Usuarios [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Roles
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

id: 1 -> rol: administrador

id: 2 -> rol: empresa

Cuando trato de crear un nuevo usuario me arroja el siguiente error, ya que por defecto no se crea correctamente rol_id de usuarios e imagino que aparece como 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ester seria el controlador de registro de usuarios:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class Register extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //include helper form
        helper(['form']);
        $data = [];
        echo view('register', $data);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        //include helper form
        helper(['form']);
        //set rules validation form
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'surname'       => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
            'enterprise'    => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
            'nif'           => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[9]|regex_match[/^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])[0-9]{7}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])$/]',
            'email'         => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]',
            'password'      => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[200]',
            'confpassword'  => 'matches[password]'
        ];



        if($this->validate($rules)){
            $model = new UserModel();
            $data = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ];
            $model->save($data);
            return redirect()->to('/aceptar'); //login
        }else{
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            echo view('register', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Que debería añadir aqui para que me creara correctamente el id de rol_id ? he hecho mal algo en la base de datos? imagino que se colocará en el registro al ser creado cierto?

He intentado crear algo así pero da error:

```
if($this->validate($rules)){
            $model = new UserModel();
            $data = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'rol_id' => $this->request->getInt('rol_id' == 2) //empresa
            ];
            $model->save($data);
            return redirect()->to('/aceptar'); //login
        }else{
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            echo view('register', $data);
        }
```

imagino que se debe de añadir por defecto como 2, aquí ya que añadirlo en el html del formulario de reigstro con un hidden lo veo bastante mal por el tema de seguridad.

Edit he probado a añadir que se guarde el dos por defecto de esta forma un poco improvisada pero nada. La verdad que no se como hacer que por defecto en la base de datos sea siempre 2.

```
$data = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'id_rol'    =>$this -> postVar(2),
                'id_rol'    => $this->request->getVar('id_rol'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ];
```

Una posible solución sería la siguiente:

```
<div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="rol" name="id_rol" id="InputForRol" style="visibility: hidden;" value="2" readonly>
                </div>
```

de este modo ya no da errores y funciona correctamente. Pero es correcto?

Que opinais? si se necesita algun aporte mas lo adjunto sin problema. GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: En la base de datos, podrías incluir el valor 2 como predeterminado en el campo rol_id y no lo envías desde el código. Se guardará como 2 hasta que hagas un `UPDATE` de dicha tabla desde el admin de tu proyecto

Comment: Como se realizaría esto? a que te refieres?

Comment: Entras a tu `phpmyadmin`, vas a la estructura de la tabla, al campo `rol_id` tocas en cambiar. Luego, en el atributo `predeterminado` seleccionas Personalizado y te aparece un campo input debajo. Ahí escribes 2. Eso hace, que cuando no envías ningún valor por consulta `INSERT`, de forma predeterminada ingresará un 2 el motor de base de datos directamente.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!